# TIdHTTP: Select outgoing IP for HTTP request?

Tags: delphi, ip, indy, idhttp

I have a machine with several different static IPs. Is it possible to select the outgoing IP address for HTTP requests via `TIdHTTP` (Indy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Indy have `BoundIP`.

```
idHttp1.BoundIP := '144.33.34.212';
```

Comment: Is there any alternative in TNetHTTPClient?